# Hello someone could help me make a specific SQL query to this table

Tags: mysql, sql

this is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `incidencias` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `impact` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I need to group by "impact" and get the most recent date of each

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM incidencias group by impact order by date desc
```

Answer (score 2):

USE this:

`SELECT * FROM incidencias GROUP BY impact ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: yes , Paz you have used right select query as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT impact,MAX (date) from incidencias GROUP BY impact

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
select max(date) from incidencias group by impact;
```

Answer (score 0):

should like this :

```
SELECT * FROM incidencias GROUP BY impact ORDER BY date DESC
```